Azure recommendation "Upgrade to the latest Azure CLI version" for VMSS at subscription level
I have been seeing a recommendation showing up across all of my account subscriptions suggesting "Upgrade to the latest Azure CLI version". I haven't got any VMs but on Linux VMSS under our subscriptions. Can someone please suggest how can I remidiate such recommendation?

I tried to see if there are any installed apps on the VMSS but there isn't anything where I can find the Azure CLI installed.

Have you tried running the command az --version in the VM?

but how to run this command on a VMSS instance? For context, the VMSS I have in my subscription is linux OS and used for running AKS cluster.

Raised support ticket with Microsoft and got this response back:
Azure Recommendations malfunction is a known issue as of now where multiple other clients are seeing incorrect count or format or type of recommendations in Azure Portal. The workaround is to keep using the MS Defender portal to check for any recommendations related to Azure Resources. If the recommendation is not relevant to your subscription or environment then you may also ignore it for now.
